# Is there a way to make a list horizontal inside of a vertical list, but also make a vertical list inside of a horizontal list CSS?

Tags: css

I have two lists. One of them is vertical and one of them is horizontal. I would like to wrap one of the lists inside of the other. My problem is that the user decides this at runtime, so making my lists `display:block` or `display:inline-block` seems to not work. Here's some example HTML

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li>
        <ul id="list2"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here are the two potential classes that `list1` and `list2` will be assigned.

```
.horizontal li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.vertical li {
    display: block;
}
```

The reason `list1` and `list2` haven't been assigned either class is because the user gets to assign them at runtime. Because of this, the outermost class seems to dictate what the innermost class does. So if `list1` gets assigned `class="horizontal"` and `list2` gets assigned `class="vertical"`, then `list2` will still be horizontal.

Another factor to note is that both of these classes might not get used. For example, the user might decide to make both the outer class, and the inner class horizontal.

Is there a way I can go about setting the CSS so that even if I don't know which list will get assigned to which class, the inner list won't have its CSS overwritten by the outer list?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just assign the outer list class then you can do this

```css
.horizontal li,
.vertical li li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.vertical li,
.horizontal li li {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal">
  <li>
    this is horizontal outer
    <ul>
      <li>this is vertical inner</li>
      <li>
        1 inner
      </li>
      <li>
        2 inner
      </li>
      <li>
        3 inner
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    1 outer 
  </li>
  <li>
    2 outer
  </li>
  <li>
    3 outer
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="vertical">
  <li>
    this is vertical outer
    <ul>
      <li>this is horizontal inner</li>
      <li>
        1 inner
      </li>
      <li>
        2 inner
      </li>
      <li>
        3 inner
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    1 outer 
  </li>
  <li>
    2 outer
  </li>
  <li>
    3 outer
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is perfect for how I phrased the question. Unfortunately, I'm now realizing that I phrased it poorly. I don't actually know if the inner list will be different from the outer list. So the outer list might be horizontal, and the inner list might be horizontal as well. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: I'm not sure. My original style works if both the inner and outer are the same, but it doesn't work if they are different. And since the user decides at runtime, I can't know whether or not they will be the same or different. Do you know if there's any other way to make lists horizontal and vertical other than using display:indent-block that doesn't have this issue?